# Pandas check if a row contains a string rather than exact match

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function to check if a row within a DataFrame contains a string. This approach does work however it will only match if the provided string is exactly the same as what is in the DataFrame and I need it to match if it contains a string.

e.g. searching for 'fox' in 'a quick brown fox' will yield no return

```
def search_excel_files(file_list, search_term):
    #list of row indexes that contain the search term
    rows = {}
    for file in file_list:
        df = pd.read_excel("files/" + file)
        for row in df.iterrows():
            if search_term in row[1].values:
                #get row index
                row_index = row[0]
                #add row index to dictionary
                rows = df.iloc[row_index].to_dict()
    return rows
```

How can I check if the row contains the provided string in this instance?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html is of no use for you?

Comment: @9769953 `if row[1].str.contains(search_term, regex=False).any():` returns the error `Can only use .str accessor with string values!` how can I access the value as a string?

Comment: Operate on the dataframe column in total: `df['column_name'].str.contains(....)`. Your code iterates over the rows, thus operates on single values (`row[1]`).

Comment: @9769953 Ok that makes sense however I am still getting the same error of `Can only use .str accessor with string values!` when looping through the 'column_name' using `for col in df.columns:`  any idea why that could be?

Comment: Because you are now doing this for all your columns (with the for loop)! If any of those columns is not of a string type (has a `None`, or is of integer type or floating point), then it obviously fails. That should be obvious from the error message.

Comment: @9769953 sorry for the noob question but how would I determine if the column contains a string?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to think in columns than in rows when using pandas

```py
df.your_col.str.contains("fox")
```

which will return an array of booleans, one bool for each row

Below you will get a dataframe where each row has fox in `your_col` column.

```py
df[df.your_col.str.contains("fox")]
```

Comment: The "regex" argument should be set to "False" if regex search isn't wanted.

Comment: @PascalVKooten in your example "your_col"  how can I iterate through the columns?  I am currently using IterRows however I do not see an equivalent for IterCols?

Comment: `[x for x in df.columns]`